# Tensorflow error while using SavedModelBuilder

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to create a SavedModel(*.pb) file in tensorflow python. I will use this protobuf file in Java. However running the following code gives me a permission denied error. I am running tensorflow-gpu on a windows machine.

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np

from imutils import paths
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array


def load_data(data_dir):
  imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(data_dir)))
  print("[INFO] loading images...")
  data = []
  labels = []
  for imagePath in imagePaths:
      # load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
      image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
      reimage = cv2.resize(image, (64,16))
      reimage=reimage.astype(np.float32)
      reimage=np.multiply(reimage,1.0/255.0)
      data.append(reimage)

      label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
      if label=="classa":
        label=0
      if label=="classb":
        label=1
      if label=="classc":
        label=2
      ll=int(label)
      labels.append(ll)

  data=np.array(data)
  print(data.shape)
  labels=np.array(labels)
  print(labels.shape)
  return data, labels


images_a,labels_a=load_data("ttt")


graph=tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    images_ph=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,16,64,3],name='input')
    labels_ph=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None],name='labels')

    dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images_a,labels_a)).repeat().batch(100)
    iter=dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    next_element=iter.get_next()

    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=images_ph,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool1, [-1,32*8*32])

    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1000, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, rate=0.4)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=3)

    predicted_labels=tf.argmax(logits,1)

    loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels_ph,logits=logits))

    train=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

    init=tf.global_variables_initializer()


with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:

  session.run(init)
  for i in range(101):
    x,y=session.run(next_element)
    loss_values=session.run([train,loss],feed_dict={images_ph:x,labels_ph:y})
    if i%10==0:
        print("Loss: ",loss_values)

  builder=tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("/pModel")
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(session,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
  signature_def_map={
  tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={"input":tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(images_ph)},
    outputs={"output":tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(logits)})
  })
  builder.save()


  test_images,test_labels=load_data("test")

  predicted=session.run(predicted_labels,feed_dict={images_ph:test_images})

  match_count=sum([int(y==y_) for y,y_ in zip (test_labels, predicted)])

  accuracy=match_count/len(test_labels)
  print("Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(accuracy))

  print(tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING)
```

When this is run it gives me the following error:

```
    2018-04-19 13:32:10.043715: W C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1202] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:220 : Permission denied: Failed to create a directory: /; Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1361, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1340, in _run_fn
    target_list, status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: Failed to create a directory: /; Permission denied
         [[Node: save/MergeV2Checkpoints = MergeV2Checkpoints[delete_old_dirs=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](save/MergeV2Checkpoints/checkpoint_prefixes, _arg_save/Const_0_0)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorv4.py", line 94, in <module>
    outputs={"output":tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(logits)})
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\builder_impl.py", line 392, in add_meta_graph_and_variables
    saver.save(sess, variables_path, write_meta_graph=False, write_state=False)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1654, in save
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: checkpoint_file})
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1137, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: Failed to create a directory: /; Permission denied
         [[Node: save/MergeV2Checkpoints = MergeV2Checkpoints[delete_old_dirs=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](save/MergeV2Checkpoints/checkpoint_prefixes, _arg_save/Const_0_0)]]

Caused by op 'save/MergeV2Checkpoints', defined at:
  File "tensorv4.py", line 94, in <module>
    outputs={"output":tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(logits)})
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\builder_impl.py", line 386, in add_meta_graph_and_variables
    allow_empty=True)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1293, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1302, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1339, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 787, in _build_internal
    save_tensor = self._AddShardedSaveOps(filename_tensor, per_device)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 411, in _AddShardedSaveOps
    return self._AddShardedSaveOpsForV2(filename_tensor, per_device)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 393, in _AddShardedSaveOpsForV2
    sharded_prefixes, checkpoint_prefix, delete_old_dirs=True)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 379, in merge_v2_checkpoints
    delete_old_dirs=delete_old_dirs, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\MoWHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

PermissionDeniedError (see above for traceback): Failed to create a directory: /; Permission denied
         [[Node: save/MergeV2Checkpoints = MergeV2Checkpoints[delete_old_dirs=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](save/MergeV2Checkpoints/checkpoint_prefixes, _arg_save/Const_0_0)]]
```

Any idea on what is going wrong. I tried running with administrator privileges but to no avail

Comment: Permission denied error comes from the OS. Try to write to a different folder, where you're certain to have write access

Comment: Thanks that helped. I changed my working folder and restarted the whole thing. Worked now.